# Does node-apn provide persistent connection?

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I've some question about node-apn. I have three iOS apps which want to send push notifications.

I created 3 connections using `apn.Connection`, is this connection persistent? Should I create a connection to APNs and send one push notification every time? Can I create a connection, then send many push notification later? What if I send first push notification one day later after I create connection?

What does `connectionTimeout` exactly do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection will maintain an underlying persistent connection, yes. You can use one `apn.Connection` per app and send all notifications through that object. If an internal connection doesn't exist it will create one and maintain it while it is necessary, if the connection fails and no notifications are pending it will not establish a new connection until more notifications need to be sent.

`connectionTimeout` will tell `apn.Connection` to close the underlying connection after a defined number of seconds if there has been no traffic. It does *not* mean that the `apn.Connection` object can no longer be used, simply push another notification and it will reopen a connection automatically.